# Number of supported screens on MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I have a [Mid-2018 Mac Book Pro](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i5-2.3-13-mid-2018-true-tone-display-touch-bar-specs.html).

On its `2nd Display Support Option` it writes the following

> *In addition to simultaneous support of the internal display, this model supports a single external display up to 5120x2880 at 60Hz at
>   over a billion color, up to two displays up to 4096x2304 at 60Hz at
>   millions of colors, or up to two displays up to 3840x2160 at 60Hz at
>   over a billion colors via Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C).

I cannot infer however from the above, whether the particular MacBook can support:

> **3** **external** displays with resolution `2560 x 1440`

Any interpretations on this?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that your MBP is limited to 2 external monitors. You can't sub-divide the same number of pixels across more displays.

Comment: However I just came across this https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/334650/connecting-3-monitors-to-macbook-pro-2018-via-thunderbolt-3. This user claims to be able to connect 3 x 4K monitors ...(?) ... and yet with an **older** macbook pro (2017)...This contradicts the specs themselves

Comment: @pkaramol The specs for the 15 inch MBP 2017 say up to 4 external monitors. 15 inch MBPs tend to have discrete GPUs which provide better function. They also have more ports.